# Liferay clustering in the same machine

Tags: localhost, liferay, jackrabbit, cluster-computing

Is there a way to give different Cluster ids to Jackrabbit when running two nodes in the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two nodes do have two home directories, right? So you should have two directories where the Jackrabbit configuration is stored (repository.xml if I recall correctly), thus you can enter the relevant ID in every single file.

If you don't have that already, I'd suggest to separate the directories for both servers.

By the way: Configuring a cluster is typically either done for stability (e.g. survive a server going down) or load distribution. In your case neither would give you benefit - what's your usecase for setting up a cluster on the same machine? Testing? Demo?

Comment: Yeah it's testing, if the tests go OK then they will go into production. Well the thing is both instances are reading it from the same location, so I want to know how to set the location that the instances will look for repository.xml (yeah you do remember correctly)

Comment: simple: You have made both instances to read from the same location - the default is that every server has their own location. However you did that: stop it and make the instances read from different locations - repository.xml is the place where you name the cluster instance. If you can't remember: try your portal-ext.properties which might hold the key for the setting, but it could be elsewhere.